# Axios GET with params being ignored

Tags: php, laravel, axios

Newbie to all the tech I'm using here.
Trying to query a table using Axios in Laravel with Vue.js. Here's what I got:

*from my component's* `<script>`

```
this.axios
    .get('http://localhost:8000/api/tasks', {params: {vid: this.properties[0].vid}})
    .then(response => {
        this.tasks = response.data;
        console.log(response)
})
```

Regardless of what `vid` is in the `params`, the response contains ALL of the table's rows.

I do know that this *may* have something to do with `api.php`, and the *Controller* associated with the request. I'll post those to be verbose.

*routes/api.php*

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
  Route::resource('vehicles', VehicleController::class);
  Route::resource('tasks', TaskController::class);
  Route::get('tasks?={vid}', [TaskControler::class, 'search']);
});
```

*Controllers/TaskController.php*

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() {
      $tasks = Task::all()->toArray();
      return $tasks;
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
      $task = new Task([
        'make' => $request->input('make'),
        'model' => $request->input('model'),
        'year' => $request->input('year'),
        'mileage' => $request->input('mileage'),
        'type' => $request->input('type'),
        'VIN' => $request->input('VIN')
      ]);
      $task->save();
    }

    public function show($tid){
        $task = Task::find($tid);
        return response()->json($task);
    }

    public function update($tid, Request $request){
      $task = Task::find($tid);
      $task->update($request->all());

      return response()->json('Task Updated!');
    }

    public function destroy($tid){
      $task = Task::find($tid);
      $task->delete();

      return response()->json('Task Deleted!');
    }

}
```

I tried for a while to mess around with `api` and the controller, but to no avail. Most of the questions asked here give "*just use params*" as an answer, but despite my best efforts I don't seem to be able to get away with "just" params (willing to be proven wrong.)

Comment: the query string in the URL is not part of the path for routing, it is inputs

Comment: You're mixing query parameters and path parameters. `/api/tasks?vid=123` vs `/api/tasks/123` which one do you want to use?

Comment: tried both, neither work.

Comment: It has to do with the order of your routes. The resource route is defined before your get route, thus it will always goes to the index method of the resource group. Try to place `Route::get('tasks?={vid.. ` before `Route::resource('tasks.. ` And make sure the search method exists on your controller, it seems missing now.